# Why does pattern match on case object fail when using -Xfuture

Tags: scala

The following code compiles fine without `-Xfuture`:

```
package sandbox

trait M

case object Obj extends M {
  def run: Unit = println("RUNNING")
}

object Sandbox extends App {
  (Obj: M) match {
    case x @ Obj => x.run
  }
}
```

But fails with it:

```
error: value run is not a member of sandbox.M
  case x @ Obj => x.run
```

Why is it assuming `x` to be of type `M` and not `Obj.type`?

By the way, it appears to compile fine with a `case class`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has to do with which equality you expect in the pattern match.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1503

```
scala> trait M
defined trait M

scala> trait X { def x: Int = 42 }
defined trait X

scala> case object O extends X with M
defined object O

scala> (O: M) match { case x @ O => x.x }
res0: Int = 42

scala> :replay -Xfuture
Replaying: trait M
defined trait M

Replaying: trait X { def x: Int = 42 }
defined trait X

Replaying: case object O extends X with M
defined object O

Replaying: (O: M) match { case x @ O => x.x }
<console>:14: error: value x is not a member of M
       (O: M) match { case x @ O => x.x }
                                      ^


scala> (O: M) match { case x: O.type => x.x }
res1: Int = 42
```

There's an `-Xlint` warning:

```
scala> (O: M) match { case x @ O => x.x }
<console>:14: warning: The value matched by O is bound to x, which may be used under the
unsound assumption that it has type O.type, whereas we can only safely
count on it having type M, as the pattern is matched using `==` (see SI-1503).
       (O: M) match { case x @ O => x.x }
                               ^
res0: Int = 42
```

Comment: Does it work if it's a sealed trait and X,M and O are defined in the same REPL line?

Comment: @pedrofurla `sealed trait M ; sealed trait X { def x: Int = 42 } ; case object O extends X with M ; (O: M) match { case x @ O => x.x }` But it knows I didn't override equals! What's the matter with that stupid thing!

Comment: Love the `:replay -Xfuture`, didn't know that existed.